# probability distribution $X, Y$ and $X+Y$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

A box contains $5$ ticket, $\{ 0 , 0 , 0 , 4 , 4\}$.

Drawing two tickets at random w/o replacement.

$X$ be the sum of the first two draws and Y be the outcome of the first draw.

Question: Find distribution of $X + Y$?

- What I did --
  I found the distribution of $X$. There are only three possible sums: $0 , 4, 8$. And there are $10$ ways to get these sums:  $(0,0), (0,0), (0,4),(0,4),(0,0),(0,4),(0,4),(0,4),(0,4) (4,4)$. Therefore $P(0) = 3/10 , P(4) = 6/10, P(8) = 1/10$.

My other question:  Is there another way (different from what I did) to get the distribution of $X$?  And I have no idea how to get distribution of $Y$.

Comment: The distribution of $Y$ is given in the problem! I imagine you want the distribution of $X+Y$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes I want to get X+Y, but I thought I need to first get the distribution of Y.  Y is given ?? really ?????  I'm confused,,

Comment: Yes @hibc, it is given. There are 2 choices for the draw 0 or 4. It can be 0 with probabiliy _____ and 4 with probability _______. Also, it follows ________ distribution since it takes one of two values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the distribution of $X$, I do not think there is a substantially better way than yours.

For the distribution of $X+Y$, we do something similar. If it helps to keep track of things, draw a tree diagram. Let $W=X+Y$.

**Case $1$:** Maybe the first pick was $0$. This has probability $\frac{3}{5}$. **Given** that this happened, the probability of picking a $0$ next is $\frac{2}{4}$. Then $W=0$. The probability of piking a $4$ is  $\frac{2}{4}$. Then $W=4$.

**Case $2$:** Maybe the first pick was a $4$. This has probability $\frac{2}{5}$. In that case, the probability of next getting $0$ is $\frac{3}{4}$, and we get $W=8$. The probability of getting a $4$ is $\frac{1}{4}$. In that case $W=12$.

So $W$ takes on values $0$, $4$, $8$, $12$.

For the probability that $W=0$, locate all the ways $W$ can be $0$. This only happens in one way, $0$ then $0$. We can see that the probability is $\frac{3}{5}\frac{2}{4}$.

Similarly, the probability that $W=4$ is $\frac{3}{5}\frac{2}{4}$.

Similarly, $\Pr(W=8)=\frac{2}{5}\frac{3}{4}$ and the probability that $W=12$ is $\frac{2}{5}\frac{1}{4}$.

As a partial correctness check, add up our four numbers. We should get $1$, and we do.

Comment: Thank you very much!! very detailed and clear !

Comment: You are welcome. I went into the gruesome detail in order to show that if one stays organized, things are likely to turn out well.